# How to fix the error reading file without any information of objects

Tags: java, file

I have an Exercise about write and read file for a list of students. The issue is that when my file is empty, the read file method says that end of file, but when I write one student to file, it still say that end of file even though my file is not empty, it has the information of students and I used method output to get information about students.
It always tell me "end of file" without the output of data and I do not know the reason.
I really appreciate with your help!

```
public void readFile(ListStudent a) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<Student> objectsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try( ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\Files\\Students.txt"))){
            boolean cont = true;

            while(cont){
                Student x = (Student) in.readObject();
                if(x != null)   
                    objectsList.add(x);

                else cont = false;
            }
            a.setArr(objectsList);
            for(Student x : a.getArr())
                x.output();
            in.close();
        }
        catch(EOFException eof){
            System.out.println("End of file");
        }
```

And the output method:

```
public void output(){
    System.out.format("%-30s%-30s%s\n", this.getName(), this.getBirthday().output(), this.getAvg_score());
}
```

Comment: Where Students.txt is being written ? Is it flushed and closed before invocation of `readFile` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `EOFException`

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.

In the example you have provided

```
Student x = (Student) in.readObject();
if(x != null)
```

`readObject` will not return null when end of file is reached it throws `EOFException`, so if there is a file with the following content:

```
StudentA
StudentB
```

`StudentA` and `StudentB` will be added to `objectsList`, but on the third execution `readObject()` will throw `EOFException`

The main issue here is how you handle this exception, try something like this:

```
while(cont){
 try{
   Object x = (Object) in.readObject();
 } catch (EOFException e) {
   cont = false; // or just break
 }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, I realize that I use the key work transient with misunderstanding, so the fields are not written to my file, but I still confused that my program throws java.io.NotSerializableException even though I let Student class implements Serializable?